# pylint: global-variable-not-assigned

Tags: python, global-variables, pylint

The code:

```
assets = {}                # line 1

def myfunc():
    global assets          # line 4

    if assets.get("a", None) is None:
        assets["a"] = 2
```

The pylint result:

```
C:  1, 0: Invalid constant name "assets" (invalid-name)
C:  4, 4: Invalid constant name "assets" (invalid-name)
W:  4, 4: Using global for 'assets' but \
    no assignment is done (global-variable-not-assigned)
```

The function will be called later more than once so I just want to assign (in real life some time-consuming process) the value only once.

How should I do it properly?

p.s.: Thanks @deceze, I was confused by the fact that if instead of `assets = {}` I use `assets = {"a":2}` the behavior will be absolutely different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The linter tells you that you're *not assigning to `assets`*, meaning `assets = ...`. Which means you do not need `global assets`. The variable `assets` from the outer scope will be available inside `myfunc` anyway *for reading*. You only need `global` if you want to assign a different value to the variable in the outer scope. `assets['a'] = 2` is not assigning a different value to it, it's just *mutating* the existing value.

So, remove the `global assets` line.